# The name <object name> does not exists in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Most questions are related with old version of `ASP.NET MVC`.
My question is related to latest `.NET Core` build on **Framework 4.6**. I created a console application and standard class library. I installed all libraries needed for running WEB on `.NET Core`.

Everything is working fine, views are compiled fine and debugging views also working. Unfortunately, **Visual Studio** shows the following on any object in view:

> The name  does not exists in the current context.

How can I get rid of these red underlines?

[image]

I am using this technique: [Running ASP.NET Core MVC as a Console Application Project without .NET Core SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128464/running-asp-net-core-mvc-as-a-console-application-project-without-net-core-sdk)

Comment: Can you add full error to post?

Comment: The error is in the title. It's kind of intellisense error. My project is compiled and runs fine. No errors in console.

Comment: Do you use some tool like `Resharper`?

Comment: Its a error, warning or message? Mby try to rebuild solution and update packages and then restore

Comment: Yes, I am using Reshaper ultimate, latest version (2016.3.1), I also tried to disable the resharper. It seems Resharper does not underline these.

Comment: Clean solution, save all, clear **Visual Studio Cache**, close **Visual Studio**, open **Visual Studio**, rebuild solution... The fact that the `@inject` is red and `var` is red indicates that this is an issue with the **VS** cache. That should work.

Comment: @DavidPine Sorry my question, How do I clear VS cache ? :)

Comment: var error says "Feature 'implicitly typed local variable' is not available in c# 2. Please use language version 3 or greater."

Comment: Hi @wh1sp3r ! I didn't notice those red underlines in my example. In fact, it was a simple demo. It may be a VS bug. BTW, right now it's possible to compile your project using Msbuild again. Do you still have any reason to use that aproach?

Comment: @FabricioKoch Hi, I solved my problem in really interesting way. I created website core on FRAMEWORK and class library on CORE. I changed project.json for class lib to use Framework 4.6 instead of NETStandard 1.6 and cshtml looks fine. So it seems there must be kind of problem in Razor host. I also tried new VS2017RC, but it's crashing :) Is it possible to provide simple example of working Razor (intelisense) in console application ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred in the initial versions of .NET Core and the tooling for Visual Studio: Basically it was as if we were running  release (not debug) build. Please upgrade to the latest versions, including Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and .NET Core tooling.

Comment: I have latest update ( Update3 ) for VS2015 and latest tooling. I am using this way to run web server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128464/running-asp-net-core-mvc-as-a-console-application-project-without-net-core-sdk

Comment: I had that exact same problem, and with the updates it went away. Weird.

Comment: Well, if i create Core class library, Views are fine, if I create classic class library, it shows underlines